# Friendly inline images with CKEditor4?

Tags: ckeditor

The users of my editor (an CKEditor-4) need to add little equations throughout the paragraph, as inline images,

```
 <p>Nononon nonon <img align="absmiddle" src="equation.png"/> nonon onno.</p>
```

How the user can manage, friendly, these inline images?  There are a plugin for it?

---

PS1: [related link](https://drupal.org/node/1983312) with some clues.

PS2: test by your self adding by source code below at http://ckeditor.com/demo

```
  <p>Nononon nonon <img align="absmiddle" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/tab-bar-ios-and-wp8-icons/20/Cloud_-_upload.png"/> nonon onno.</p>
```

The tool not offer "inline" align, and if you change, can't back to the inline... No support for inline images.

Comment: Doesn't CKEditor come with a "smiley" dialog built in? I'm fairly sure I have customized that one in the past to accommodate for all sorts of images (although IIRC that was version 2 or 3)

Comment: No with CKEditor-4.X, if I put this paragraph with source, then edit with image tool interface, the tool destroys the image format, and the tool not offer an "absmiddle" align option.